# How to perform search query with mongo and mongoose with react.js?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, search, mongodb-atlas-search

I've been having trouble with creating a search component in this project. Basically, the idea is that the search query will take in a `name` and the search will filter the database finding products that coincide with or are like `name`.

Ultimately, I've tried using a `.find()`:

```
const product =  await Product.find({ name: new RegExp(name, 'i') })
```

which works well on the backend when tested with POSTMAN as it takes in `name` which is  `const name = req.body.name`

However, when implemented on the front-end, the following error occurs:
Frontend:

```
    const handleSearch = async (e) => {
        const product = {search}

        const response = await fetch('/api/products/search', {
            body: JSON.stringify(product),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            } 
        })
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body
```

So, I began wondering if ATLAS search is the way to go, or is there a fix to this error

How would i go about using ATLAS search and react.js together?

**Edit**
So after implementing the `req.query` the backend API endpoint still works as expected and the frontend does seem to send the correct query, however now the json result is not being sent back
Below is code

```
const handleSearch = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(search)
        const product = {search}
        const response = await fetch(`/api/products/search?${new URLSearchParams(product).toString()}`)

        const json = await response.json()
        
        if (!response.ok) {
            setError(json.error)
        }

        if (response.ok) {
            setError('')
            setSearch('')
            setFilterProduct(json)
        }

    }
```

the above code is in react and does send the fetch with the correct query and search input, however  `FilteredProduct` returns nothing even through it has been set as the json.

```
const searchProduct = async (req, res) => {
    const search = req.query.search
    console.log(req.query.search)
    const product =  await Product.find({ name: new RegExp(search, 'i') })

    if (!Product) {
        return res.status(400).json({error: 'enter proper search'})
    }

    res.status(200).json(product)
    
}
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending request body for `GET` request, try sending query params, like this:

```
const handleSearch = async (e) => {
      const product = {search};
      const response = await fetch(`/api/products/search?${new URLSearchParams(product).toString()}`)
 }
```

Comment: Would i have to change my API endpoint for this from /search to something else

Comment: No, just read the query params from `req.query` object rather than `req.body`,

Comment: `name = req.query.search`

Comment: let me know if it works or not

Comment: I implemented your advice and explained in the edited post above

Comment: try querying the mongodb directly, to see if it's returning any data or not

Answer (score 0):

Note that you are not using Atlas Search here, just a simple MQL `find` call with a regular expression. In order to use Atlas Search (assuming you have created a [search index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/create-index/)) you have to use the `aggregate` method passing an aggregation pipeline with the [`$search`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/query-syntax/) stage.

Comment: Is it possible to continue using find or must i change to thid atlas search method

Comment: If you want to use Atlas Search, you must to use the `aggregate` method and pass a pipeline array with `$search` as the first stage. If you want to continue using `find`, you can only use the legacy text indexes or regex expressions, but not Atlas Search.